# Questions about Python

Tags: python

I have been using python to do algebraic calculations, but at many times when writing 1/2 Python writes 0.5, but I wanted you to write 1/2 and only when needed, convert it to a float.

I'm having a hard time imposing a simplification because Python doesn't recognize 32.0 as being 32, in short example situation where I have.

$\frac{(32.0-64x)^2}{4096}$

Since the answer could be

$\frac{(1-2x)^2}{4}$

Comment: That's just how most programming languages work. If you want to do symbolic math, you need to use Maple or Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do symbolic math, there's a python-module called [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

In order the achive what you want here, you could do the following:

```py
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import simplify
f = (32 - 64 * x)**2 / 4096
print(f) # (32 - 64*x)**2/4096
print(simplify(f)) # (2*x - 1)**2/4
```

Comment: I've been using the python-module sympy, but it doesn't have simplification.

Comment: @PEDROMORAIS, it does have simplification. I suggest that you check [SymPy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html). If you have similar questions you could use the mailing list or [Gitter](https://gitter.im/sympy/sympy).

Comment: @nicoguaro Checking the SymPy documentation. I found the command `nsimplify()`which find a simple representation for a number or, if there are free symbols or if rational=True, then replace Floats with their Rational equivalents. If no change is made and rational is not False then Floats will at least be converted to Rationals.

Comment: @PEDROMORAIS, I suggest that you ask in Gitter. This is not the place to have this discussion.

Comment: @PEDROMORAIS, also. I suggest that you accept the answer.